# Accessing Data from Stored Procedure using CallableStatement

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have written a Stored Procedure as shown , which will be responsible to give the 
list of the EMployee Numbers

```
create or replace procedure
kiran
as
CURSOR cur is select * from emp;
TEMPCUR cur%rowtype;
begin
open cur;
loop
fetch cur into TEMPCUR;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TEMPCUR.empno);
exit when cur%NOTFOUND;
end loop;
close cur;
end;
/
```

Please tell me how can i retrive this values from a JDBC program

callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(kiran);

// Please help need logic here

Comment: I presume the target database platform is Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you do it. Remember, the last parameter in my example is actually declared in the PL/SQL procedure as an "OUT" parameter, e.g. the value you want to return in the form of a parameter):

conn  --- is the connection object

cstmt --- this is a callablestatement

```
   cstmt = conn.getNewCallableStatement("{call MY_PLSQL_PACKAGE.MY_PROC(?,?,?)}");
           cstmt.setString(1, stringOutput1);
           cstmt.setString(2, stringOutput2);
           cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
           cstmt.execute;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it with exactly the procedure you listed, but you can easily do it if you change your procedure to return ref cursor. There are numerous examples of doing that. Here's the first one from Google search results: http://www.enterprisedt.com/publications/oracle/result_set.html .

**EDIT:**

Based on the changed stored procedure definition, the JDBC command would look like this:

```
{? = call test}
```

You will have to create a CallableStatement with this command, register an out parameter of type Oracle REF CURSOR and execute it. You will get your results as the first output parameter:

```
            ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)stmt.getObject(1);
```